# Authorize doesn't work for API calls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth, authorization

I am building a .NET FW WebApp that have both a WebSite and WebApi.

I setup OAuth 2.0 using the Visual studio 2015 Template projects,
with a bit of change.

Register/Sign-in and Out and [AuthorizeAttribute] on the Controllers work just fine!

Also, I have several `class Foo:ApiController{}` to handle Ajax requests,
which works well given a **Bearer Token**.

I Encountered a problem when i needed to submit **Multipart-Formdata** to the API.
and Saw that `User.Identity` did not exist, and [Authorize] fails to pass. (Even though Requests to the `Controller`s (Not the `ApiController`s) run smooth.

I am pretty new to Web Development, so i am probably missing something fundamental.

- Checked cookies passed with the `Form.submit()` are the same as any other Page request.
- Even simple GET request from an ApiController fails to authorize.

  1. What information should i post in order to help you help me?
  2. What is the difference between my `Controller` and `ApiController` classes in terms of Authentication & Authorization?

Answer (score 1):

I knew it's something Basic.

For whom, who is as unfamiliar with the Visual Studio 2013 Web-API Project Template.

The Auth & Auth *for your Site* is defined by `Startup.Auth.cs`
while *for the WebApi* it is at `WebApiConfig.cs`

in `WebApiConfig::Register(...)` there is a line `config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();` which prevents the already configured CookieAuthentication to work on `ApiController` calls.

Hope this helps anyone